# Is it safe to re-symlink the 'open' command from `openvt` to `gnome-open` on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

On my Ubuntu systems, `bin/open` is symlinked to `openvt`. I'm not sure what this program does, but I'd like to delete the symlink and symlink or alias `open` to `gnome-open`. Is this safe to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modified symlink is likely to get redone by an update at some point. An alias or a wrapper script earlier in your `PATH` should be perfectly safe.

For your information, `openvt` runs a command on the first available virtual terminal. If you're not using it, you're not likely to need it and the system doesn't depend on it as far as I know.